# Dynamically changing size of img on hover with jQuery changes position of imgs around it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I've got a simple empty HTML div:

```
<div id="spaceTrainingImages"></div>
```

I am adding images dynamically to it:

```
// adds the images to the img div
imgContainerSpace = $("#spaceTrainingImages");
for (var i = 1; i <= numStimuli; i++) {
  imgContainerSpace.append(
    $("<img>", {
      id: "spaceTrainingImg" + i,
      src: numToPath(i),
      style: "width:30px;height:40px",
      "class": "spaceTrainingPic"
    })
  );
};
```

Moreover, I change the dimension of each img as the mouse hovers over it.

```
// deals with size change on mouse over
$(".spaceTrainingPic").hover(function() {
  // img gets three times bigger
  $(this).css({
    "width": "90px",
    "height": "120px",
  });
}, function() {
  // img returns to original size
  $(this).css({
    "width": "30px",
    "height": "40px",
  });
});
```

I would like the imgs to be at the center of the div and remain there:

```
#spaceTrainingImages {
  position: relative;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: snow;
}

.spaceTrainingPic {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

This works whenever the mouse is not hovering over any image. However, whenever I hover over an image, all the other images move. Their top becomes the bottom of the image being hovered (which becomes bigger).

I am not sure what might be causing this.

---

EDIT: I had forgotten to mention that I do want the imgs to move to the sides when the hovered over image gets bigger, I just don't want them to move vertically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use transform **scale()** instead of changing height and width value.

As I see you are changing values 30 to 90 and 40 to 120 which is 3 times of original value so use `transform: scale(3);`

```
$(".spaceTrainingPic").hover(
  function() {
    // img gets three times bigger
    $(this).css({
      "transform": "scale(3) translateY(-50%)"
    });
  },
  function() {
    // img returns to original size
    $(this).css({
      "transform": "scale(1) translateY(-50%)"
    });
  });
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  imgContainerSpace = $("#spaceTrainingImages");
  for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    imgContainerSpace.append(
      $("<img>", {
        id: "spaceTrainingImg" + i,
        src: 'https://www.jquery-az.com/html/images/banana.jpg',
        style: "width:30px;height:40px",
        "class": "spaceTrainingPic"
      })
    );
  };
  $(".spaceTrainingPic").hover(function() {
    $(this).css({
      "transform": "scale(3) translateY(-16.666667%)",
      "z-index": "1"
    });
    $(this).next("img").css({
      "margin-left": "30px",
    });
  }, function() {
    $(this).css({
      "transform": "scale(1) translateY(-50%)"
    });
    $(this).next("img").css({
      "margin-left": "0px",
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#spaceTrainingImages {
  position: relative;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: snow;
}

.spaceTrainingPic {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  transition: all .3s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="spaceTrainingImages"></div>
```

Comment: I tried this but (1) the imgs around it do not move to the sides so that the bigger img partially covers them, (2) they move to a different position after the hover (down)

Comment: @FaustoCarcassi see...if the images become bigger other will be covered...for second point change your transform to `scale(1) translateY(-50%)`...because you have already aplied transformY(-50%) before...

Comment: In the version I posted the pictures around move horizontally so there is no overlap even when one becomes bigger. The problem is that they also move vertically

Comment: Yes and it does work better! In the sense that the other imgs are not moved vertically, however they do not move horizontally anymore so there is overlap (see edit of question)

Comment: @FaustoCarcassi See updated answer!...you have to add some margin to the next image as well....:)

Comment: That's almost perfect! The only thing is that the movement only works for the images on the right of the hovered image, but not for the ones on the left.

Comment: I made the addition myself and now it works perfectly!

Comment: @FaustoCarcassi Great...!...Glad it helped...:)

Answer (score 0):

this can be done quite simply without so much javascript and just pure css.
First when you foreach create div and inside append the image.

This div can have class `img-wrapper` with

```
.img-wrapper {
  width: 30px;
  height: 40px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

    .img-wrapper img {
       width: 100%;
       height: auto;
       transition: all 0.3s linear;
    }

    .img-wrapper:hover img {
        transform: scale(1.2);
    }
```

So basically 
You need something like this

```
<div id="spaceTrainingImages">
   <div class="img-wrapper">
      your img here
   </div>
   <div class="img-wrapper">
      your img here
   </div>
   <div class="img-wrapper">
      your img here
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a transform property in CSS which helps to ZOOM the element content without disturbing the others. Take a look at below

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // adds the images to the img div
  imgContainerSpace = $("#spaceTrainingImages");
  for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    imgContainerSpace.append(
      $("<img>", {
        id: "spaceTrainingImg" + i,
        src: 'https://www.jquery-az.com/html/images/banana.jpg',
        style: "width:30px;height:40px",
        "class": "spaceTrainingPic"
      })
    );
  };

  // deals with size change on mouse over
  $(".spaceTrainingPic").hover(
    function() {
      // img gets three times bigger
      $(this).css({
        "transform": "scale(3)",
        "z-index":"1"
      });
    },
    function() {
      // img returns to original size
      $(this).css({
        "transform": "scale(1)"
      });
    });




})
```

```css
#spaceTrainingImages {
  position: relative;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: snow;
}

.spaceTrainingPic {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="spaceTrainingImages"></div>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Runnin this code you can see that after the images have been hovered over, their position changes. Also I had forgotten to say that I do want the images to move to the sides, just not to move vertically (see edit)

Answer (score -1):

I think you would be better of using the tranform css property.

```
$(".spaceTrainingPic").hover(
  function () {
      // img gets three times bigger
      $(this).css({
        "transform": "scale(3)"
      });
  }, function () {
      // img returns to original size
      $(this).css({
        "transform": "scale(1)"
      });
});
```

---

You could also do this with pure css

```
.spaceTrainingPic:hover {
  transform: scale(3);
}
```